# Prevent to reopen the application Android Developer

Tags: android

Its simple question and hope to find quick answer.
When I open the application and press "home", after that click on 
the app icon it's open again (still keep open already one in background).
How to force to reopen the app from background instead of open a new one?

This problem dont occur when I'm using longpress "home" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the `android:launchMode` variable in your `activity` tag in androidManifest.xml. Depending on your app, `SingleTop` or `SingleTask` could work like what you want. See the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want this for testing purposes you can use the force close button in settings. If its a feature of your app try

```
onPause(){
super.onPause();
finish();
}
```

I haven't tested this so i could be wrong.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite from what is wanted? This closes the app when it's switched to the background and always opens a new instance instead of reopening from the background.